# What was the first randomized experiment that was ever conducted?

Tags: biographical-details, philosophy-of-science

C.S Peirce is credited by wikipedia with the invention of randomized experiments.
What was C.S Peirce's contribution to randomized experiments exactly if there were such experiments before Peirce?
How did the psychophysicists whose results Peirce was improving when he discovered the principles of randomized experiments conducted their experiments?